# search a square brackets string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, string, ms-access

iam making a dictionary in mediawiki and for this purpose i designed a bot in vb.net 
when i search in a string which contains [[ code dosne detect the [[ in a string a seems it bypass the [[ code is below

```
 dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM data"
            dbCommand.Connection = dbConn
            dbConn.Open()
            Dim dbDR As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader

            While dbDR.Read
                Dim mydata As String = CStr(dbDR("mean".ToString))
                If InStr(mydata, vbNewLine & "[[اسم نکرہ]]") Then
                    Dim myid As String = dbDR("ID".ToString)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(mydid)
                End If
            End While
```

this code search for vbNewLine & "[[اسم نکرہ]]" in the string and then add myid to listbox but it search "اسم نکرہ" also (without [[) so it mix up. where iam making mistake?

Comment: Mixing punctuation with right-to-left rendered languages can be quite tricky.  At least experiment with the InStr overload that takes a CompareMethod so that you can specify Text instead of the default of Binary.  Your default culture plays an important role as well.  Further diagnose trouble with String.ToCharArray() and favor String.IndexOf() so you can choose a StringComparison.  Last but not least, square brackets are an escape character for SQL statements.

Comment: In line with Hans' comment, are you sure it is the square brackets? The string is found for me, although I did not test against a database.

Answer (score 0):

Use : `dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE mean like '%[[اسم نکرہ]]%'"`
Note some old ms access version dont support `%` in `like` query so use `*`

so you are filtering data from it source, no need to filter it in VB.net

Comment: That is not true, the wild card is either * or % depending on ANSI-89 or ANSI-92 : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HA010076601.aspx

Comment: i cannot use sql query because i need to filter the data several times after getting from ms access database. if there is any other way?